# How to automate deb package with binary?

Tags: debian, deb

I have following issue:

I have access only to binary file. From a binary file I am trying to make a full automated `.deb` package. I packaged it and works except the service file.

I created service file under debian folder

```
hello
-- hello
-- debian/hello.service
```

my rules file looks as below

```
$ cat debian/rules

    #!/usr/bin/make -f

    %:  
             dh $@
    override_dh:install:
            dh_install hello usr/bin
```

package is creating but it doesn't started service as well as not create 
service file under `/etc/systemd/system/`.

postinst file as below
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e

```
if [ $1 = configure] || [$1 = abort-upgrade]; then
    if [ -x /etc/init.d/hello ]; then
        update-rc.d hello defaults >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the appropriate systemd service helpers (`dh_installsystemd` in compatibility level 12).

The simplest way to go about all this is to rely on `dh` sequences; it will do the right thing, even when there’s nothing to build:

```makefile
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
        dh $@

override_dh_install:
        dh_install hello usr/bin
```

This will ensure that all the other helpers are run as appropriate in the sequence, including the systemd helpers.

With debhelper compatibility levels less than 10, you’ll need to enable the systemd sequence explicitly:

```makefile
%:
        dh $@ --with systemd
```

(The service file will end up in `/lib/systemd/system`, not `/etc/systemd/system`.)

You could even drop the override altogether, if you write

```
hello usr/bin
```

into `debian/install` (or `debian/hello.install`, assuming your package is named `hello`).

Comment: my package is called hello and my binary also called hello. Yes hello.service  file is created by the system under the path you said, but the app doesn't start still automatically,

Comment: I didnot set any version of -dh, what you mean exactly ?

Comment: What I mean is, did you replace your `debian/rules` with the short version in my answer, or did you keep your existing `debian/rules` and add `dh_installsystemd` to it?

Comment: I tested again, no success. see rule file ^ added to question

Comment: What version of Debian are you building on? What debhelper compatibility level are you using?

Comment: Debian 9 and compatibility debhelper >= 9

Comment: With compatibility level 9, you need to enable systemd support, see my update.